# Duda sobre controller

Tags: angularjs, controller

Estoy trabajando en angularjs, y tengo un ejercicio con dos ficheros, miPanel.js donde hay un controller que se llama miPanelCtrl y trae esto controllerAs : 'miPanel'.
Luego está el otro fichero que se llama miPanelMedico.js donde hay un controller que se llama miPanelMedicoCtrl y trae lo mismo que el de arriba controllerAs : 'miPanel'.
Cuando en un evento por ejemplo `ng-click = "miPanel.busqueda()"` como sabe que controller quiero o hace la búsqueda en los dos ficheros y se queda con el que tenga la funcion busqueda?

Comment: Estaría bien que pusieras el código que te crea la duda, pero si defines dos controladores con la misma etiqueta, creo que el segundo que se cree *sobreescribe* al primero, eliminándolo

Comment: Lo intenté pero no se cómo puedo subir el codigo, pero lo unico que quiero saber esq si se puede tener dos controller con un controllerAs: miPanel.  Aunque los ficheros js esten en carpetas diferentes

Comment: subir el código: le das a [edit] tu pregunta y simplemente copias y pegas el código relevante. Después lo seleccionas y pulsas Ctrl + K para formatearlo

Comment: En base a la situación propuesta, sin mirar el código: Dependiendo del controller que está unida la vista en la que estés usando la directiva `ngClick` (tu evento), te va a ejecutar la función que está definida en ese controller asociado, sea de un fichero o del otro.

Comment: Ya resolví la duda, gracias unas líneas arriba del ControllerAs, había esto templateUrl: 'templates/paciente/miPanel.html'. El controller se dirige al fichero que está ahí, por eso los eventos los distinguen.

Answer (score 0):

si preguntas como sabe angular cual controlador debe sacar el valor `controllerAs : 'miPanel'`, la respuesta es en el controllador que le has seleccionado en la ruta ejemplo..

### en el siguiente ejemplo hay 2 rutas y cada una señala a un controlador

```
.when('/miPanel1', { //ruta destinada
  templateUrl: 'miPanel1.html', //archivo html donde estara el boton que envia la accion
  controller: 'miPanel' //(controlador relacionado) 
});
.when('/miPanel2', { //ruta destinada
  templateUrl: 'miPanel2.html',//archivo html donde estara el boton que envia la accion
  controller: 'miPanelMedico' //(controlador relacionado)
});
```

cuando tienes el evento `ng-click = "miPanel.busqueda()"` en el path o ruta `/miPanel1` tomara el valor del controlador que tiene relacionado en este caso `miPanel.js`